# What is the best way to express "this year's teaching material is better than last year's"?

Tags: translation, grammar

I want to say:

> This year's teaching material is better than last year's

今年的教材比去年的好。

Is the above correct or do I have to include 教材 again?

今年的教材比去年的教材好。

In English one doesn't have to repeat ''teaching material''. I am wondering if the same goes for Chinese.

Comment: Both are fine. It's a valid omission.

Comment: You don't need to repeat.

Comment: Further to other commentators' recommendations, I would omit the 2nd "的" which is not "wrong" per se but stylistically unnecessary. Fine Chinese writing favors structural brevity and abhors non-productive repetitions and verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is just fine, because there're also ellipsis in Chinese. You can also skip the last `的` in the first sentence, so you'd get `今年的教材比去年好。`.